# How to convert string to json object using DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4, anypoint-platform

How do I convert below input string (which will be retrieved from config.yaml properties file) to required json object using Dataweave?

Input:

```
"ABC:123,DEF:456,GHI:789"
```

Required Output:

```
{
    "ABC":"123",
    "DEF":"456",
    "GHI":"789"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splitBy and reduce can be used like below

```
("ABC:123,DEF:456,GHI:789" splitBy ",") reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> 
    accumulator ++ 
    do
    {   
        var items = item splitBy  ":"
        ---
        (items[0]): items[1]
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---

{(("ABC:123,DEF:456,GHI:789" splitBy ",")  map {
    ({ (($ splitBy ":")[0]): (($ splitBy ":")[1])})

})}
```